# dynamic radio buttons uitableview custom cell ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create dynamic radio buttons using custom cell .I tried and able to create using story board. but how to allow only one radio button selection?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   MChangeServiceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"changeServiceCellidentifier"];

   cell.serviceLabelView.text =@"test";



   cell.radioButton.tag=indexPath.row;


   [cell.radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonColorChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      return cell;
}

- (void)radioButtonColorChange:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
   NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
   MChangeServiceTableViewCell *tappedCell = (MChangeServiceTableViewCell *)[self.listTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
   if ([tappedCell.radioButton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_unselected.png"]])
   {
      [tappedCell.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else
   {
      [tappedCell.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```

I am able to change the image of the radio button by clicking on it.But how to change the remaining radio buttons to unchecked state when one button is clicked?

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you so save current selected button in another variable.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *currentBtn;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentSelectedIndex;

@end
```

Then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   _currentSelectedIndex = -1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     MChangeServiceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"changeServiceCellidentifier"];

     cell.serviceLabelView.text =@"test";

     cell.radioButton.tag=indexPath.row;

     [cell.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
     [cell.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonColorChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [cell.radioButton setSelected:NO];

     if (indexPath.row == _currentSelectedIndex) {
         [cell.radioButton setSelected:YES];
         _currentBtn = cell.radioButton;
     }

     return cell;
}

- (void)radioButtonColorChange:(id)sender
{
   _currentBtn.selected = NO;
   UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
   button.selected = !button.isSelected;
   _currentBtn = button;
   _currentSelectedIndex = button.tag;
}
```

Comment: ,I used the above code and I can able to select radio button.but when I scroll the tableview  I can see cells from bottom has one of the cell radio button is selected state.

Comment: still the same result. other cells getting button images selected.

Comment: check now i edited the answer and if my answer is helpful you can mark as accepted and up vote it

Comment: Thank you very much .it helped me a lot. one final question,if I want to add one more button in same tableviewcell and enable/disable it on some condition(irrespective of the radio button).should I follow the same approach? any idea.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with same approach