# How to change a image when when we click a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, radio-button

I'm working with radio buttons, for this i'm writing code like this.

```
float x = 40;
float y = 0;
for (int i=0; i<self.radioBtnTagArr.count; i++) {

        self.radioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.radioButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+35, 35.0, 35.0);
        [self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.radioButton];
        self.radioButton.tag = [[self.radioBtnTagArr objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        y = y+70;

    }
```

This "self.radioBtnTagArr" comes from server (tags comes from server), based on that count i want to create radio buttons and i'm assigning tag that tags to radio buttons.

```
- (void) radioBtnMethod:(UIButton *)sender {

for (int i=0; i<self.radioBtnTagArr.count; i++) {

    if (sender.tag == [[self.radioBtnTagArr objectAtIndex:i] intValue]) {

        [self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [self.radioButton setSelected:YES];

    }

}
}
```

Now the problem is when i click first radio button the last radio button was selected like this below image...

[image: Radio button image]

I want only when we click first button first button state selected, if we click second button second button state selected like this...

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618690/dynamic-radio-buttons-uitableview-custom-cell-ios/44632164#44632164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like create another one array for save the UIbutton, for e.g

**Step-1**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableArray *buttonArray;
```

**step-2**

add the all buttons to buttonArray

```
   // allocate the memory for your array
  buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i<self.radioBtnTagArr.count; i++) {
        // create instance value of UIButton
        UIButton *radioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         radioButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+35, 35.0, 35.0);
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.radioButton];

        y = y+70;
       // add the object to array
       [buttonArray addObject:radioButton];

    }
```

**step-3**

inside the target

```
 - (void) radioBtnMethod:(UIButton *)sender {

  // reset the previous selection
  for (UIButton *getradioButton in buttonArray) {
       [getradioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
   // set the current selection
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453747/parsing-array-of-json-inside-object-in-swift